# How to stop and restart consuming message from the RabbitMQ with @RabbitListener

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rabbit

I am able to stop the consuming and restart the consuming but the problem is that when I am restarting the consuming, I am able to process the already published message but when I publish the new messages those are not able to process.

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Consumer;

@Component
public class RabbitMqueue implements Consumer {

int count = 0;

@RabbitListener(queues="dataQueue")
public void receivedData(@Payload Event msg, Channel channel, 
          @Header(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_TAG) String tag) throws IOException, 
                InterruptedException {

count++;
System.out.println("\n Message recieved from the Dataqueue is " + msg);

//Canceling consuming working fine.
if(count == 1) {
    channel.basicCancel(tag);
    System.out.println("Consumer is cancle");
}

count++;
System.out.println("\n count is " + count + "\n");

Thread.sleep(5000);

//restarting consumer. able to process already consumed messages
//but not able to see the newly published messages to the queue I mean
//newly published message is moving from ready to unack state but nothing 
//happening on the consumer side. 

if(count == 2) {
    channel.basicConsume("dataQueue", this);
            System.out.println("Consumer is started "); 
    }       
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must not do this `channel.basicCancel(tag)`.

The channel/consumer are managed by Spring; the only thing you should do with the consumer argument is ack or nack messages (and even that is rarely needed - it's better to let the container do the acks).

To stop/start the consumer, use the endpoint registry [as described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/index.html#_container_management).

> Containers created for annotations are not registered with the application context. You can obtain a collection of all containers by invoking `getListenerContainers()` on the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` bean. You can then iterate over this collection, for example, to stop/start all containers or invoke the `Lifecycle` methods on the registry itself which will invoke the operations on each container.

e.g. `registry.stop()` will stop all the listeners.

> You can also get a reference to an individual container using its id, using `getListenerContainer(String id)`; for example `registry.getListenerContainer("multi")` for the container created by the snippet above.

Answer (score 4):

If your are using AMQP/Rabbit, you can try one of these:

1) Prevent starting at startup in code:

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

    //
    //autoStartup = false, prevents handling messages immedeatly. You need to start each listener itselve. 
    //
    factory.setAutoStartup(false); 

    factory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
    return factory;
}
```

2) Prevent starting at startup in  in app.yml/props:

```
rabbitmq.listener.auto-startup: false
rabbitmq.listener.simple.auto-startup: false
```

3) Start/stop individual listeners

give your @RabbitListener a id:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "myQ", id = "myQ")
...
```

and :

```
@Autowired
private RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry;

MessageListenerContainer listener = 
   rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("myQ");
    ...
listener.start();
...
listener.stop();
```